# What am I.........?

Tags: riddle

> I have same thing inside and outside.
>
> I have very less time to even see my creator , I die very quickly.
>
> Sometimes I am big , sometimes I am small

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is:

> An air bubble

I have same thing inside and outside.

> Air is present both inside and outside.

I have very less time to even see my creator , I die very quickly.

> They usually burst quickly.

Sometimes I am big , sometimes I am small

> They can be big or small.